# Percentage of Duration of deactivation in R

Tags: r, tibble

I want to compute the percentage of the durations a system is deactivated. 
The activation is given in a column "Active" where 1 means Activation and 0 means deactivation. The observations (rows) correspond to different readings from different systems identified by their "ID". The "Time" of each reading is identified in timestamps.
Here is a sample of the data I have in a tibble.

```
ID Timestamp Active
64 1512743947      1
74 1512743963      1
76 1512743978      1
80 1512743992      0
22 1512744041      1
74 1512744155      1
80 1512744175      1
51 1512744240      1
80 1512744266      0
80 1512744275      1
```

I followed the response to my question here: [Extract change duration in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864712/extract-change-duration-in-r/54866351?noredirect=1#comment96528009_54866351). But I figured out that the sum of the timestamps difference won't get me to where I want to be. So to be clear, as a response I would like to have the total percentage of time each ID spent deactivated which means between 0 and 1 (not 1 and 0).

```
ID Percentage
80 67%
```

Comment: Are the timestamps regular (e.g. there will be an observation every minute) or irregular?

Comment: @Jordo82 they are irregular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Active) > 1) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = lead(Timestamp) - Timestamp) %>%
  summarise(
    Percentage = scales::percent(sum(time_diff[Active == 0], na.rm = T) / sum(time_diff, na.rm = T))
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     ID Percentage
  <int> <chr>     
1    80 67.8%
```

Here I presumed on the basis of your output that you'd like to filter out those cases where it is either 100% or 0%.

Otherwise you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = lead(Timestamp) - Timestamp) %>%
  mutate(
    Percentage = sum(time_diff[Active == 0], na.rm = T) / sum(time_diff, na.rm = T),
    Percentage = scales::percent(coalesce(Percentage, +(Active == 0) * 1))
  ) %>% 
  distinct(ID, Percentage)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   ID [6]
     ID Percentage
  <int> <chr>     
1    64 0%        
2    74 0%        
3    76 0%        
4    80 67.8%     
5    22 0%        
6    51 0%
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you. This seems to work. Is there a way to put the result in a file ?

Comment: You're welcome! Check functions such as `write.csv`, `write.table`, `fwrite` in `data.table`, for `XLSX` you also have packages such as `xlsx`, `openxlsx`, etc.